# Skoda Superb 2018 Clock Spring

Tags: skoda

I have a 2018 Skoda Superb. The airbag light is on, the horn doesn't work and all of the wheel electronics are dead: so I guess the clock spring is dead.

Would anyone be able to point me towards the part number so I can purchase a replacement? It doesn't need to be 1st party as long as it works.

Also, is this a job that I can do myself or is it really a garage job?

Comment: Have you checked with your Skoda dealer?

Comment: I've been unable to get a call-back despite 2 weeks of trying @jwh20

Comment: Is there one local to you?  Perhaps you simply show up and visit the parts department.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I live in the arse end of Scotland

Answer (score 0):

Is this it perhaps?  There is more than one variant of the Superb but this looks promising:

[Skoda Clock Spring](https://skodapartsdirect.co.uk/product/skoda-superb-estate-2016-present-clock-spring/)